# Angular/NodeJS/Express App not working on mobile

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, http, express

I have an application that I created that runs Angular 6, NodeJS, Express and Mongo.

Currently, the app is deployed to a DigitalOcean droplet and works without error on desktops & laptop browsers. Whenever I try to log in over a mobile device (smartphone, tablet etc.) the connection times out. I have used remote device debugging via Chrome but it is slow, unresponsive and pretty much useless.

I have set up `@angular/pwa` and `@angular/service-worker` to the point that I simply ran the install commands. I haven't configured anything, as I am still trying to figure out what I need. I'm unsure if that is the cause of the problem. I am looking for some direction or someone who has had a similar problem that may have a solution.

The droplet is running Ubuntu 18.04 with Nginx. I have used certbot and LetsEncrypt to get the SSL going. The NodeJs is managed via PM2.

What I'm looking for is help with trying to evaluate why everything works fine on desktops/laptops but not on mobile. The app is meant for field use, so mobile functionality is critical.

Comment: Are you redirecting mobile users to a subdomain such as m.mywebsite.com? Might be a CORS issue and you need to whitelist the subdomain.

Comment: Maybe the mobile device doesn't have LetEncrypt as a trusted root CA?  Is your full app served over https? Maybe the mobile device doesnt support the TLS version/key size.  There is some tool online to check your https setup.  I think it was `qualis` who provided it. It can show which protocols/devices are supported in your current setup.

Comment: @ToneCrate - no redirects or other situations you describe

Comment: @jcuypers - Verified using the TLS tool you recommended. received an A rating with functionality across Chrome, Android and Safari. No indication of issues. Worth noting, I can pull up the front end (login) with no issues. The 500 response comes when trying to login. sometimes it takes several minutes to register the timeout.